# How do I get my return to show when testing in a console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wrote something in a text editor and went to test it in the chrome console. It evaluated fine, but there was no return. How do I view my return?

```
function strict() {
"use strict";

function getAllParaElems() {
    var KeepPtag = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    return ("Here is the jist:" + KeepPtag);
}
}
```

Comment: You can call `console.log(getAllParaElems())` to print result in console.

Comment: @ivan that should be the answer.

Comment: @agconti Posted as answer, thanks for tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `console.log(getAllParaElems())` to print result in console.

Comment: This sounds like it will work. I just ran into something called a JSLint error when adding the console.log. "console was used before it was defined."